# Payment method address capture error

Tags: magento2

I've Apple Pay as payment method, after filling the shipping address and check the checkbox of my billing address is same as my shipping address I get an error.

But after that if I refresh the page the order placed successfully which mean it happened only for the first time.

Could you please help me.
This is the beginning of error log :

```
{"0":"Please check the shipping address information. \"firstname\" is required. Enter and try again. \"lastname\" is required. Enter and try again. \"city\" is required. Enter and try again.","1":"#1 Magento\\Quote\\Model\\SubmitQuoteValidator->validateQuote() called at [vendor\/magento\/module-quote\/Model\/QuoteManagement.php:529]\n#2
```